# handler path in Nest.js

Tags: typescript, express, nestjs, handler

I have this `PATCH` request: `http://localhost:3000/tasks/566-344334-3321/status`.

With the handler for that request:

```js
@Patch('/:id/status')
updateTaskStatus() { // do stuff 
    return "got through";
}
```

I dont understand the mechanics behind the stem part and how the correct handler gets assigned to handle the request.

So from `/566-344334-3321/status`
The id part is /566-344334-3321 which can be any value.
But the stem ending  `/status` needs to be exactly  `/status`.
If not, a `"error": "Not Found"` occurs.

What is the underlying logic behind this behavior ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get your `id` parameter, you need to use the `@Param` decorator to assign the `:id` in your request to a typescript number.

Here is how you'r supposed to write your `updateTaskStatus` function according to the [NestJS documentation about Route Parameters](https://docs.nestjs.com/controllers#route-parameters)

```js
@Patch('/:id/status')
updateTaskStatus(@Param('id') id: number) { 
    return `Got ${id} through`;
}
```

If you question was to use the `status` as a dynamic value like `id`, you need to apply the same decorator to your parameter

```js
@Patch('/:id/:status')
updateTaskStatus(@Param('id') id: number, @Param('status') status: string) { 
    return `Got ${id} and ${status} through`;
}
```

The NestJS documentation is very good and complete, don't hesitate to read the [documentation about the controllers](https://docs.nestjs.com/controllers)